# Flutter - The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type is a potentially non-nullable type

Tags: flutter, dart, return, flutter-listview

I'm trying to show a list of search results. The error is with the ListView Builder.

```
ListView.builder(
          itemCount: searchResults.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            final searchResultAccount = searchResults[index];
            for (var element in searchResults[index].profile!) {
              final searchResultProfile = element;
              return ListTile(
                leading: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundImage: searchResultProfile.profileImage.isNotEmpty
                      ? NetworkImage(
                          searchResultProfile.profileImage,
                        )
                      : null,
                  child: searchResultProfile.profileImage.isNotEmpty
                      ? null
                      : const Icon(
                          Icons.person,
                        ),
                ),
                title: Text(
                  searchResultProfile.profileName,
                ),
                onTap: () {
                     //navigate to profile
                },
              );
            }
            if (searchResults.isEmpty) {
              return Text('no results');
            }
          },
        ),
```

I tried putting the code inside a try-catch block and even with the conditional statement above that I added in the end to return Text widget I'm still getting the same error.

How to clear this error?

Comment: can you post the error log? it will be more clear.

Comment: put a debug pointer on itemCount and check what value he have..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that we will get null value from `searchResults[index].profile`. Therefore, loop may not return any `ListTile` widget.
Also, while using loop, it will return a list of widget. But you are returning single `ListTile`. You can wrap with `Column`.

`searchResults.isEmpty` may not meet the criteria and won't return `Text(..)`. You can include an else statement and return a widget.

```dart
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
  final searchResultAccount =....;
   List<Widget> xWidgets = [];
  for (var element in searchResults[index].profile!) {
    xWidgets.add( ListTile(..));
  }

 if (xWidgets.isNotEmpty) {
          return Column( 
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: xWidgets,
          );
        }

  
   return Text('no results');
 
},
```

Comment: Also, I prefer checking null value then using `!`, for your case check `.profile!`

Comment: I think you mean "It is possible that `searchResults[index].profile!` is empty." `searchResultAccount` isn't used at all.

Comment: Thanks, feel free to update the answer

Comment: column children is the list xWidgets, right?

Comment: Yap, I am using `Column` while and while it takes list, I am doing `children: widgetsX,`

Comment: xWidgets or widgetsX? I thought it might be a typo. and used the list xWidgets. It works. Thank you so much

Comment: Oh yes, that's a mistake, I will do an update

Comment: This is not related to the above question but I have an issue with my initState function. I'm getting the results and everything works but the results show up on screen only after a hot reload. I have similar issue with home screen where the profile details show up only after page is rebuilt either by doing a hot reload or when i navigate to another page and come back. I think its due to how cache is being handled. Could you help with this please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243067/discussion-between-rawm-and-yeasin-sheikh).

Comment: @YeasinSheikh https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71529230/flutter-refresh-page-if-data-isnt-loaded-on-screen

Answer (score 0):

I would say that one of the parameters are being sent as null, try dugguing to find out where it is sending the error.

Also the for seem a bit inappropriate as it will only iterate once and return the first element of the profile at that index. You can achieve the same getting the first element.